# unable to access the static variable

Tags: c++, class, static-variables

```
#include <iostream>

class test
{
    int a, b;

public:
    static float f;
};

float test::f;

int main()
{
    test::f = 3.14;
    std::cout << f;
}
```

"unable to access the static variable" even though I am using the class label.

Comment: Not for `cout<<f`. What's the full error message you get?

Comment: try `cout << test::f;` and you probably should have initialized f here `float test::f`

Comment: cpp.sh shows `error: 'f' was not declared in this scope`  on the line `std::cout << f`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` function has no variable named `f`.

Change this line:

```
std::cout << f;
```

To this, which is probably what you meant.

```
std::cout << test::f;
```

[See it working.](https://www.ideone.com/tn47Jz)